# Merge Table Contents in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have two tables named `ITEM` and `Transaction`. I want to write a query to retrieve the Name, Unit, the *balance for the price and the *balance for the quantity.

- for the balance price = Price - TPrice
- for the balance quantity = Quantity - TQuantity

Here is the structure of my tables

`ITEM` table:

```
  ID
  Name
  Unit
  Price
  Quantity
```

`TRANSACTION` table:

```
  ID
  Item_ID
  TQuantity
  TPrice
```

How can I query all the items including that have no values for `TQuantity` and `TPrice`?

```
  ITEM TABLE
  |ID | Name     | Unit | Price  | Quantity |
  | 1 | KeyBoard | pc.  | 1223.00| 4.00     |
  | 2 | Mouse    | pc.  | 1234.00| 3.00     |
  | 3 | Alcohol  | btl. | 900.00 | 6.00     |
  | 4 | Scissors | pc.  | 200.00 | 4.00     |

  TRANSACTION TABLE
  |ID | Item_ID | TQuantity | TPrice |
  | 1 |  1      | 2.00      | 800.00 |
  | 2 |  2      | 1.00      | 500.00 |

  RESULTS TABLE
  |ID | Name        | Unit  | Balance Quantity | Balance Price |
  | 1 | Keyboard    | pc.   | 2.00             | 423.00        |
  | 2 | Mouse       | pc.   | 2.00             | 734.00        |
  | 3 | Alcohol     | btl.  | 6.00             | 900.00        |
  | 4 | Scissors    | pc.   | 4.00             | 200.00        |
```

Comment: Apply join on `Item_ID` and in select do the calculation

Comment: Show some sample data and some desired output. Also, show what you have tried to solve this so far. That way people can advise you on where you are going wrong rather than simply doing the work for you. You'll learn a lot more that way.

Comment: It will only show items that have values on TQuantity and TPrice. The rest of the items that don't have TQuantity and TPrice will not show.

Comment: I already edited my question showing my desired output. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the left join to get the all items and there quantity and price, and use `COALESCE` to handle the `NULL` values. You never mentioned what do you want for calculation if the `TPRICE` and `TQuantity` are null that's why I am assuming you need them as it is.

```
  SELECT 
       t.Price - COALESCE(tt.TPrice,0) AS balanceprice ,
       t.Quantity - COALESCE(tt.TQuantity,0) AS balancequantity,
       t.Name,
       t.Unit
  FROM 
        [databasename].[schema].[itemtable] t WITH(NOLOCK)
        LEFT JOIN  [databasename].[schema].[transactiontable] tt WITH(NOLOCK)
            ON t.ID = tt.Item_ID
```